# How to place plugin hook in a wordpress template

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

In many `WordPress` `plugins`, there are instructions that Place `<?php do_action('plugin_name_hook'); ?>` in your templates.

where exactly this code needs to be placed and what should be the `plugin_name_hook`?

Answer (score 0):

hooks are actions performed at a time.
If you want a custom hook then
1.create your custom hook in your plugin or theme's function.php

```
add_action('my_action','my_function');
function my_function()
{

// do something
}
```

2.and call it in your template as

```
do_action('my_action');
```

and you can read more here
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action

Comment: I am using a plugin that requires to place the do_action in the template as you mentioned, but where exactly in the template I mean which file

Comment: you can use it anywhere in your template file

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like plugins that you still need to modify your theme's template file manually. What is the use then of a plugin.

To come back to you question though, your `do_action()` call will need to go in the template where you need to display the output of the plugin. Say it is a plugin that add social share buttons to the content, you will need to add the `do_action` after `the_content()` in your template files.

The second part of the question, the `plugin_name_hook` will be specified by the specific plugin. So far that you have to follow the installation instructions of the plugin